# Angular RxJS Poll real-time data switchMap type error

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

I am trying to poll real-time data from my server with RxJS using `interval` and `switchMap`. When the user navigates to the component it'll trigger the poll. I got it working by requesting HTTP endpoint directly (instead of extending the base class) with the following service code.

myService.ts:

```
public getRealTimeData() {
    return interval(5000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.httpClient.get('http://myendpoint:3000/endpoint');
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

However, I can't wrap my head around why when I extend a base service class, and do the same thing in the base class it gives me an error

myService.ts:

```
...
constructor(){
    super(httpClient, 'my_custom_route')
}

public getRealTimeDataExtendingBaseClass() {
    return interval(5000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        this.requestURLBase();
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
}
```

baseService.ts:

```
protected baseUrlPrefix = 'api/v1/';
constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, route: string) {
   this.route = route;
}

...

public requestURLBase() {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrlPrefix + this.url); 
}
```

Here is the error stack:

```
errors.ts:30 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.exports.subscribeTo (subscribeTo.ts:27)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.ts:36)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.ts:139)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.ts:128)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at AsyncAction.dispatch (interval.ts:75)
    at AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.ts:122)
    at AsyncAction.execute (AsyncAction.ts:97)
    at AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.ts:58)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
```

Comment: Its the Curlybrackets in the switchmap. Either remove those or use return `this.requestURLBase()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot return of the request stream.

```js
switchMap(() => {
  return this.requestURLBase(); // <- return!!!
}),
```